# show that linear functional is continuous

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces, metric-spaces

Consider linear functional $T:C([0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, $f \in C[0,1]$, $T(f) = f(1)$.

How to that $T$ is continuous in $C[0,1]$ wrt $\left\lVert f \right\rVert =\sup_{t \in [0,1]} |f(x)|$.

And is it $T$ continuous in $C[0,1]$ wrt $\left\lVert f \right\rVert = (\int_0^1 |f(x)|^2)dx)^{1/2}$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you have standard norm on $\mathbb C$

In the first case: take any $\epsilon >0$, take $\delta = \epsilon$, then for any $g,f \in C([0,1],\mathbb C)$ such that $||f-g|| < \delta$ (so in particular $|f(1)-g(1)|<\delta$ ) we have $|T(f)-T(g)|<\epsilon$

In the second case, note that taking function $f\equiv 0$ and $g_n(x) = \begin{cases} 0 & x \le1-\frac{1}{n} \\ \sqrt[4]{n} & x=1 \\ linear & x \in (1-\frac{1}{n},1)\end{cases} $ then

$||f-g_n||^2 = \int_0^1 |g_n|^2(x)dx \le \frac{1}{n} \cdot \sqrt{n} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \to 0$, but $|T(f)-T(g_n)| = \sqrt[4]{n} \not \to 0$

Answer (score 1):

For the first show that $T$ is bounded with respect to the $\Vert\cdot\Vert_\infty$-norm.

I think $T$ isn't continuous with respect to the second norm, which you can show by taking a sequence of continuous functions $\{f_n\}$ such that $\Vert f_n\Vert_2\rightarrow 0$ but $T(f_n)\rightarrow \infty$. I think continuous functions $f_n$ satisfying that:

- $f_n(1)=\sqrt{n}$
- $f_n(x)=0$ for all $x\leq 1-\frac{1}{n^2}$.
- $\vert f_n(x)\vert\leq \sqrt{n}$ for all $x\in [0,1]$.

wil work.